# Как правильно отправить запрос requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, запрос

Есть сайт `https://www.sportmaster.ru/`, хочу отправить запрос на авторизацию, запрос идет на `https://www.sportmaster.ru/web-api/v1/auth/phone/code/`, при отправке запроса получаю 400 код, что означает `bad request`, судя по всему, без куков 403, хотел бы понять почему и как правильно отправить запрос.

Отправляю запрос следующим образом:

```py
import requests
session = requests.session()
number = '1111'  # тут номер
url = 'https://www.sportmaster.ru/web-api/v1/auth/phone/code/'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
           'cookie': 'qrator_jsr=1676010154.104.OEk3sdfhjcVdJIsr-br1o6c98p5t3ro31c1bd7rq0apgvm6ve-00; qrator_jsid=1676010154.104.OEk3sdfhjcVdJIsr-l5sd8s2b5rtqnjp8e0sma197ko93o4ci; qrator_ssid=1676010154.596.NxuFJexW1hY4JRvv-8hnlk8l3un3enhff62ugp5hcdgt7tejt; UDID=f46a5704-7eab-401c-8196-dab04883fba1; SMID=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI0Mjk0ZWM4My1iMjNkLTQzYTYtYTY3OS01NGRjODJkYWUyOTYiLCJpc3MiOiJTTTMwIiwiaWF0IjoxNjc2MDEwMTU4LCJhdWQiOiJzcG9ydG1hc3RlciIsImFuVCI6IjRkNzI3MGJlLTU3ZmYtNGQyZi1iNzBhLWU2YjkyMzk3NjUzOCIsImFuUCI6IjlhYjJmNDI5LTMxN2QtNDRmNi04YjI0LTQzNTk2ZjdlNWVlMSIsInYiOiJWMSJ9.PF-8j1uCFUryvZanf7jRpuUPsNrbWKPbnqrUv3xoGqMzGLQ0psHs-XEIivlOcFzW0-IruiZpKeLUojT3-QwW4WWsqN37KQJO5tEYxW6uH9FZSsz8D_Wg_Uqy_9W9rqr6ih0rwwlOk61xy9Al_aEMPMpSblugRfd11YbHfmFk5Urms1RPiYD1wN1vFBQpmUKC02NbNl_cWW-7RbWdxDO_xi3xCFAtfAMSLVEtqoBO5MVP3d_5BqocoUd1i_ByTM1-gu9ffzQBKh3PZ0Lr16J1g-Jgxo9FSD5snQQVAAgrCx9O5nn_4FKQNba-Q4IkKJVkIiuPs6WpXf837aTnppv1MA; SMAUTH=eyJpZCI6IjlhYjJmNDI5LTMxN2QtNDRmNi04YjI0LTQzNTk2ZjdlNWVlMSIsInN0IjoiTkVXIiwidG0iOjE2NzYwMTAxNTh9; srv_id=31725576a4a2dc204727229170299305; userAuth=0; tmr_lvid=385192a961982ef3eea2b5010a108629; tmr_lvidTS=1676010162321; _gid=GA1.2.1435283262.1676010162; _ym_uid=1676010162648212753; _ym_d=1676010162; st_uid=3a427165f97330cd8d1bc1fdddb5114d; _ym_isad=2; uxs_uid=5347c420-a90b-11ed-9564-d38cdcc89799; _ym_visorc=w; adrdel=1; adrcid=Aizf9TYB5Ifh6LeTNHw9zKg; ins-nonlogged-cartaban=false; spcount=3; _ga_Z7E27793QJ=GS1.1.1676010162.1.1.1676010226.59.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.177262356.1676010162; tmr_detect=0|1676010229068',
           'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
           'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
           'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9',
           'content-type': 'application/json',
           'origin': 'https://www.sportmaster.ru',
           'referer': 'https://www.sportmaster.ru'}
r = session.post(url, data={'phone': number, 'typeChannel': 'SMS'}, headers=headers)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите как заполняет запрос браузер. Включите отладку у requests и убедитесь, что все заголовки указаны (мб отсутствие какого-нибудь условного Accept приводит к той ошибке), а данные отправляются правильно. Включение отладки: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2b5973b5e24bfaf3bf4372482ddc96f13e42aa94/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L7-L23

Comment: @gil9red обновил вопрос, добавил еще заголовки, включил отладку по вашему способу, результат тот же

Comment: заполнил вообще все заголовки как браузера, но код ответа 400..

Comment: json={'phone': number, 'typeChannel': 'SMS'}

Comment: @СергейШ помогло, спасибо

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, значит не внимательно проверяли - при `data=` словарь заполняется по другому и передается с другим типом (Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded), при `json=` - `application/json`

Comment: @СергейШ, оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'qrator_jsid': '1676014498.597.dtsvi2ZYSe3nnRzi-dbnmrje3iiekdfor2ppcf19su8nhm6e0',
    'SMID': 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJiY2JmNGUyYi1jMzk1LTQwOTMtYWM5Mi04OTY2M2Q0NDEwYjciLCJpc3MiOiJTTTMwIiwiaWF0IjoxNjc2MDE0NTMxLCJhdWQiOiJzcG9ydG1hc3RlciIsImFuVCI6ImU4YzMxMWU3LTI2YjQtNDNhZC1hY2Q3LTQ5YjA4YWE2ZTU1NyIsImFuUCI6ImQ0YzdmYmM1LTE0OGYtNDRiYS1hNzIzLTQ4Nzg2NzFjNDQwNCIsInYiOiJWMSJ9.dx1IyYHfzVisOf24N7c7kMlbbBdMEHF2DFTCsjABpC1rvDPTcoonwWxWmcx-RJlKbj5QU8r2sTTpMldHyvC3g4pmUVbrVVr-WedY9WhWP4IdJ1X1zsB8W-e13lTVhdSquVpXhFz_yudAowSrYqjbo9iO3gx9S_sdapLwkB1JsolhBJmlQhf39lMtO__BkThbrn7OOKpmpoIAz4uqxnizZP_tgk0-19hbO_vo76VMFXjRbUVPhldcWQd6g-YA_ScObpo_woMdG2HK_IuJbLphvITxSJXGG74eH0_fPs6JuYHl4ZEWxQBHxl9thDDbBO12uiujDU_pv7QRjQknGtvnfw',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0',
    'X-SM-Accept-Language': 'ru-RU',
}
phone = '1111'
json_data = {
    'phone': phone,
    'typeChannel': 'SMS',
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.sportmaster.ru/web-api/v1/auth/phone/code/',
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
    json=json_data,
)
```